# mySQL update question

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-error-1248

Hey all i im getting this error when trying to update a table in my database:

**Every derived table must have its own alias**

Here is my mysql query i am trying to update with:

```
 UPDATE (SELECT clientinfo.idNumber, clientinfo.theCompName, clientoffers.idNumber, 
 clientoffers.expTimeWaiting, clientoffers.theDateStart,
 clientoffers.theDateEnd, clientoffers.theOffer, clientoffers.isActive, 
 clientoffers.theType, clientoffers.fixedAmount, clientoffers.fixedUsed
 FROM clientinfo, clientoffers
 WHERE clientoffers.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber
 AND clientoffers.theDateEnd >= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.theDateStart <= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.idNumber = 'NB351560'
 AND clientoffers.isActive = 'YES')
 SET clientoffers.fixedUsed = clientoffers.fixedUsed + 1
```

That seems OK but doesn't seem to work for some reason?

Any help would be great! :o)

**UPDATE**

```
 sqltemp = "UPDATE clientinfo, clientoffers SET clientoffers.fixedUsed = clientoffers.fixedUsed + 1 WHERE clientoffers.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber" & _
             "AND clientoffers.theDateEnd >= '2010-06-03'" & _
             "AND clientoffers.theDateStart <= '2010-06-03'" & _
             "AND clientoffers.idNumber = 'NB351560'" & _
             "AND clientoffers.isActive = 'YES'"
        oRecordset.Open sqltemp, oConnection,3,3
```

It gives me the error of
**ODBC driver does not support the requested properties.**

I'm using Mysql 5.1 with classic ASP.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a select there? is that even necessary?

Why not:

```
 UPDATE clientinfo, clientoffers

 SET clientoffers.fixedUsed = clientoffers.fixedUsed + 1

 WHERE clientoffers.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber
 AND clientoffers.theDateEnd >= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.theDateStart <= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.idNumber = 'NB351560'
 AND clientoffers.isActive = 'YES'
```

or even further, if there is a foreign-key-constraint on the two tables for `idNumber` (or you can assume every `clientoffer` entry always has a corresponding `clientinfo` entry):

```
 UPDATE clientoffers

 SET clientoffers.fixedUsed = clientoffers.fixedUsed + 1

 WHERE clientoffers.theDateEnd >= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.theDateStart <= '2010-06-03'
 AND clientoffers.idNumber = 'NB351560'
 AND clientoffers.isActive = 'YES'
```

Comment: I'm no ASP expert. Though from the looks of it, you are trying to retrieve rows returned (oRecordSet.open). The update statement does not really return rows, so what you probably need to use is an ado command

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_command.asp

Comment: It ended up being a problem with the " & _ at the ends of each sql line. Took those out and it works fine. Thanks Vin-G! :o)

Comment: Oh, right! You could still probably retain those by adding a trailing space inside the string ie "AND clientoffers.theDateEnd >= '2010-06-03' " & _. Anyway, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The "clientoffers." isn't valid outside the parentheses, so you need to create an alias for the select statement (try UPDATE (SELECT...) foo SET foo.fixedUsed = foo.fixedUsed + 1

However, it's simpler to have the update work on a single table at a time:

```
UPDATE clientoffers
SET fixedUsed = fixedUsed + 1
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE
clientoffers.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber)
AND clientoffers.theDatEnd >= '2010-06-03'
AND clientoffers.theDateStart <= '2010-06-03'
AND clientoffers.idNumber = 'NB351560'
AND clientoffers.isActive = 'YES
```

Except, depending on the MySQL version, the EXISTS subquery syntax may not be supported.  If this is the case for you, you can:

a.) Upgrade MySQL or switch to another DB engine
b.) Use your code to run the select in a loop, and then, for each returned row, issue a single update statement, remembering to lock both tables.

Comment: Doing that it gives an error of "You can't specify target table 'clientoffers' for update in FROM clause"